# Fetch latest data from Gemini model to build chat bot

Tags: large-language-models, chat-bots

I am building a chat bot based on gemini pro model through prompt engineering. The use case is simple. It allows user to ask a question about something specific which entails generating info about current event or past history. Though the model is performing well on past data, I am unable to get it to answer info beyond Gemini's cut off date (Sep 2023 or so). Has anyone tried fetching data beyond gemini model's cut off date with luck? Please suggest prompts.

So far I tried prompts like:

1. Ensure the response includes the most recent data and updates as of {today}
2. Retrieve the latest information from Google search as of {today} to provide the answer
3. If the source provides a publication date, strictly filter for results dated {today}. Else, refer to the source with latest information from {today}.

Today is a variable of today's date.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.